# I can't find and fix the error in the code

Tags: python, django

I'm a beginner and I'm creating my first website on DJANGO and when writing the code I get this error

```
products.append(Product(body,'red','100 pcs','9999 rub','4500 gramm'))
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Product' object has no attribute 'append'
```

please help me find what the code error is and fix it

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse,HttpRequest 
import random
class Product:
   __MAX_ID = 0
    def __init__(self, name:str, color: str, availability: str, cost: str, weight: str):
        self.id = Product.__MAX_ID
        self.name = name
        self.color = color
        self.availability = availability
        self.cost = cost
        self.weight = weight
        Product.__MAX_ID += 1

    def __str__(self):
           return (
            f'{self.name}\n'
           + f'color: {self.color}\n'
           + f'availability: {self.availability}\n'
           + f'cost: {self.cost}\n'
           + f'weight: {self.weight}\n'
           
        )

products=Product('nuke','red','100 pcs','9999 rub','4500 gramm')

def test(request:HttpRequest):
    body=request.body.decode('UTF-8')
    products.append(Product(body,'red','100 pcs','9999 rub','4500 gramm'))
    return HttpResponse('\n'.join(str(product) for product in products))`
```

I tried to change the product, but alas, nothing happened.maybe I have poor programming knowledge

Answer (score 1):

You define products to be a single object of type Product:

```
products=Product('nuke','red','100 pcs','9999 rub','4500 gramm')
```

and your Product class does not have an append method.

Maybe you wanted products to be a list?

```
products = []
```

Comment: I want to insert the body instead of the name "to change it at any time" maybe you know how to do it